# disable label click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create radio button and labels in one div called `Contentarea`. the problem I am having right now is both radio button and label are clickable, anyone would  please tell me how can I disable the click event of label in the following code.

```
<div id="ContentArea" class="contentarea">  </div>
```

```js
$("#ContentArea").click(function(evt) {
    $("#ContentArea").empty();
    $("#lblarea").empty();
    $("#btngroup").empty();
    var clicked = evt.target;
    var currentID = clicked.id || "No ID!";
    var type = clicked.value;
    if (type == "button") {
        loadlabelpagebyID(currentID);
    } else if (type == "raidobutton") {
        loadlabelpagebyID(currentID);
    };
});

function loadradiobuttonpagebyID(pageid) {
    $.get("HeadachePROData.xml", function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('Pages').each(function() {
            $(xml).find('Page[id="' + pageid + '"]').each(function(i) {
                pagetype = $(this).attr("type");
                nextpageid = $(this).attr("nextpage");
                backpageid = $(this).attr("backpage");
                sessionStorage.setItem("nextpageid", nextpageid);
                sessionStorage.setItem("backpageid", backpageid);
                $(this).find('nav').each(function(i) {
                    var btntext = $(this).text();
                    navpageid = $(this).attr("navpage");
                    navtype = $(this).attr("type");
                    var testbtn = $('<input type="radio">', {
                        value: navtype,
                        id: navpageid
                    });
                    var $radiolabel = $("<label>").text(btntext);
                    $radiolabel.removeAttr('onclick').off('click');
                    $("#ContentArea").append(testbtn);
                    $("#ContentArea").append($radiolabel);
                    $("#ContentArea").append("<br/><br/>");
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: If you disable the `input` then the label click action will also be disabled. If you want to stop the `label` click only (which is a bit silly IMO) then you can change the HTML generated so that the `input` is outside of the `label`.

Comment: Don't do that. Labels are clickable for a reason, they make the control easier to use.

Comment: Users are used to the labels of radio buttons being clickable. Removing this ability will make your site less user-friendly.

Comment: thank you all for your comments. You are right, I shouldn't disable the label after the radio button. I have other dynamically created label pages(label only) which also has click event enabled, I will try the code below to disable them. thanks again

Answer (score 15):

This can also be achieved with just css though please take note, browser support is limited in IE:

```
label {
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Browser support
https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: Please add this will not work in IE9, which is a widely supported browser still!

Comment: this makes the input (checkbox and radio button) non-clickable. Tested on google chrome.

Comment: Only if you wrap your input with the label, I would personally go with the first approach here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Answer (score 6):

It's entirely inadvisable, but you can attach a click event to the label, check that the label itself was clicked, and prevent default if that is the case.  See below:

```js
$('.cancel-click').on('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.nodeName === 'LABEL') e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
/* just demo styles */
label {
  float:left;
  clear:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox"> Clickable Label</label>
<label class="cancel-click"><input type="checkbox"> Non-Clickable Label</label>
```

Comment: this stopped working. Inputs inside labels are unfortunately inputs. Im pulling my hair over this!